# Print a barcode to represent a string in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, barcode

I am trying to print a list of words and the equivalent barcode.  I copy the work select it and change the font to Code 128 size 20 but it will not scan once I print it.  What do I need to do to get it to scan?

Comment: To be able to generate a valid baroda need to follow specifications:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

Answer (score 0):

### A bar code is not merely a font but a specific setup.

In Word, you should use the DisplayBarCode Field. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/cbc893c0-9683-416d-84c6-407a92451c19?redirectedfrom=MSDN) on this field from Microsoft.

It must conform to the standard: ISO/IEC 15417:2007.